# Warn about table recreation on table change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

By default, if you try to change a table using the designer making any of the following changes, you get an error message:

- You change the Allow Nulls setting for a column.
- You reorder columns in the table.
- You change the column data type.
- You add a new column.

Error message:

[image]

I know that one can turn this off by changing the "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation' option in SSMS options.

I find that for some tables, (the ones with important data in them), I want this warning. However, for a lot of other tables, I don't care whether they get blown away and then re-created. Right now, I'm just constantly changing the setting back and forth, but what I'd really like is a way to be **warned** but still be given the option to proceed anyway.

Is there any setting anywhere that would cause behaviour like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the option is to either always prevent it or to not warn you at all.

What you should do, is merely learn and understand what types of changes *will* force SSMS to drop the table and re-create it, or stop using the designer UI altogether and use DDL. In some cases you can write DDL such that it doesn't have to drop and re-create the table (SSMS isn't smart enough for all of these cases), but in all cases at least you'll know what's going to happen.